# How can I design a NoSQL database with categories and subcategories?

Tags: database, nosql

I am designing a NoSQL database with different categories. These categories can have subcategories.
Let's say, I have a category "Cook", and this category has a subcategory "Cuisines" with values "Italian", "French", etc.
Another category could be "DJ" with subcategory "Genres" and values "Rock", "Pop", etc.

What would be the best way to design this?

I was thinking about something like:

```
{
    "category": "Cook",
    "cuisines": ["Italian", "French"]
}
```

But then I am unsure how I would query these, since the name of the subcategory changes.